# gnuplot: Use only last n line

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I'm using a python script to record data from two temperature sensors to a .csv file. For every reading (every 5 mins) a new line is added to the end of the file. How can I get gnuplot to only use the last 288 lines, so I will end up with a graph for the last 24 hrs?

Thanks!

:*Edit*:

Got it, thanks for the hint @Istvan Chung.

A simple

```
plot '< tail -n 288 datafile.csv' using ...
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: I haven't used gnuplot, but something along the lines of `tail -n 288 <file> | gnuplot -p -e "set datafile separator \",\"; plot '-'"`?

Comment: Glad to see you've solved this; it's generally best to post your (full) solution as an answer so that people can see that it's been solved.

Comment: @IstvanChung Maybe you could answer the question and get a few rep points in the process, since you suggested the solution anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy solution here is to use the unix [`tail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) command to select the last 288 lines.

I suggested in a comment that

```
tail -n 288 <file> | gnuplot -p -e "set datafile separator \",\"; plot '-'"
```

should work. According to an edit on the original question, the correct syntax here was of the form

```
plot '< tail -n 288 datafile.csv' using ...
```