# How can I plot Real-Time data in GNUPLOT? The data is coming from a file that is constantly recording new data to it

Tags: linux, graph, plot, gnuplot, real-time

I would like to be able to plot data 'real-time' using gnuplot
Specifically, for example,
I have a file "foo.st" which is a data file, separated by columns.
The data in "foo.st" is collected real-time from live variables
I would like to have gnuplot open and plotting the data from "foo.st" as its continuously recording data. Ideally I want the plot to show a "1 second" plot, then refresh showing the next "1 second" of data, then refresh again showing the next "1 second" of data ...
Right now, I have a gnuplot script "foo.p" which reads:

```
set autoscale
set xtic auto
set ytic auto
set title "Leg Position"
set xlabel "Time (sec)"
set ylabel "Position"
plot "foo.st" u 1:2,'' u 1:3,'' u 1:4,'' u 1:5,'' u 1:6,'' u 1:7
pause 1
replot
set xrange [1:2]
replot
pause 1
set xrange [2:3]
replot
pause 1
set xrange [3:4]
replot
...
```

Etc I keep having to redefine the xrange to show a 1 second frame of data and then run the replot command.

Can anyone offer any other suggestions to go about this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23587104/2604213 for a possible solution using the `tail` command line tool.

Comment: Interesting!! Will try this soon and comment back with results

Comment: @Christoph Using 'tail' works much more efficiently for what I need it for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gnuplot 4.6 intruduced loops (`while () {..}`, `do for [] {..}`).

If you cannot upgrade:

```
 if !exists("t") t=0
 dt=1
 set xr [t:t+dt]
 plot "data"
 pause 1
 t=t+1
 reread
```

But I'd recommend using a `while`-loop.